# mariadb problem with users defined with "%"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I had a server running MySQL 5.1 suffer a crash recently. We happened to have a Synology NAS that has MariaDB v10 and phpMyAdmin on it so we decided to use it.

I imported the most recent mysqldump from the crashed server and that imported into MariaDB without apparent issue.

However, I was unable to get users connected to the database using their previous credentials (ex. joeblow@%). I was able to get past this by creating a user with a specific host callout (ex. joeblow@pc01).

I'd like to resolve this issue since defining users with specific hosts is tedious. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: May want to ask this over on [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have you changed `skip-name-resolve`?

Comment: No, I have not changed anything since importing the database. I have added users with specific host names but that's it.